# Java - know the obj which have my current object in attr

Tags: java

I'm sure the answer is easier than I think, and I'm a little exhausted so sorry if you find my question .. dumb.

Let us consider the two following classes :

```
public class Objet1 {
     private Objet2 obj;
     //getter & setter
}

public class Objet2 {
    public void myFunc(Objet1 objj) {
    // blabla
    }
}
```

in myFunc I need to have access to some methods of Object1, that's why I have Object1 in params.
Is there any other solution to access it ? 
Cause i have to write something like `Object1 ob = new Object1(); ob.getObject2().myFunc(ob);`
and I don't think/know if it is a good use of java..

I'm in the Object2 class' and I want to know if it is possible to have access to the Object1 which have my actual Object2 in attr without passing him throught another param

Thanks in advance, and sorry if i didn't use the goods terms, it is certainly why i didn't find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ob.getObject2().myFunc(ob);
```

can also be shortened to

```
ob.myFunc();
```

by adding the following:

```
class Objet1 {
    private Objet2 obj;

    public void myFunc() {
        this.obj.myFunc(this);
    }
}
```

Related reading:

- [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)
- [Delegation Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
It's simple, it's working great, and it's seems to be the best solution in my case.
Thank you for the related reading too  !

Answer (score 0):

You can make myFunc `static`, then you access it from outside with

```
Objet2.myFunc(ob);
```

But if you make your function `static` you can't access instance variables of your Objet2 instance and it would make more sense to put `myFunc()` in your Objet1 class then. The "correct" implementation depends on what you want to do in `myFunc()`.

Answer (score 0):

To access an object you must have a reference to it. So you must either pass the reference as an argument, as you already do, or have the reference stored in some static variable somewhere, which is not a good idea. 
May be you should move the function to Object1

```
public class Objet1 {
     private Objet2 obj;
     //getter & setter
     public void myFunc() {
       // blabla
    }
}
```

if the function is using some properties of Object2, may be merge Object1 and Object2 into single class.